# How do I access text from <a> tag with Beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access text from a `<a>` tag via Beautifulsoup.

Page I'm working with: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKPIs.png)

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def test():
    url = 'http://gsapqv1/qlikview/index.htm'
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

    all_applications = []

    applications = soup.select('a.name')
    for app in applications:
        print(app.text)
    

test()
```

So in the end i want a list the names of all applications on the page.

I am new to web-scraping and I'm trying to follow tutorials but I'm having a hard time finding the problem/solution.

Comment: Hey @Filpekann Welcome to SO! the URL that you have provide in code is not giving any respones so, can you update your code with active URL

Comment: @BhavyaParikh Oh, sorry. How do I make my URL active? I tried opening the URL from a different device and it worked. The URL should send you to this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKPIs.png

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the working URL (*This site can’t be reached*), the only thing I could suggest is `.select_one()` `bs4` method which will grab only one element:

```py
# grab text from <a> tag
>>> soup.select_one(".favorite.favOff").a.text
30 - Cap Rep calc.qvw
```

```py
# grab URL from <a> tag
>>> soup.select_one(".favorite.favOff").a['href']
href link..
```